# A question about a theorem in *Quantum dynamical semigroups generated by noncommutative unbounded elliptic operators*

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, semigroup-of-operators, unbounded-operators

I'm studying the paper **Quantum dynamical semigroups generated by noncommutative unbounded elliptic operators** by Changsoo Bahn and Chul Ki Ko and Yong Moon Park(https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0505026v1).

I have a question on the proof of theorem 3.1 in page 15 of this paper, in which a part of deduction goes as

> \begin{align}
> &[W^2-\sum_{l=1}^d(W_l)_l,W_k\partial_k+\partial_kW_k]\\=&[W^2,W_k\partial_k+\partial_kW_k]-[\sum_{l=1}^d(W_l)_l,W_k\partial_k+\partial_kW_k]\\=&-2W_k((W^2)_k-\sum_{l=1}^d(W_l)_{lk})
> \end{align}

where $W=(W_1,\cdots,W_d)$ is a function $:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, $(W_i)_k$ is the $k^{th}$ derivative of $W_i$ and $W^2=\sum_{i=1}^d (W_i)^2$.

I am stuck in the last equal sign, for which I think we need for $A,B \in \mathcal{D}$:

$$[A,B\partial_k+\partial_k B]=-2B(A)_k.$$

But my calculation for this goes as:

\begin{align}
&[A,B\partial_k+\partial_k B]+2B(A)_k\\=&AB\partial_k+A\partial_kB-B\partial_kA-\partial_kBA+2B\partial_kA-2BA\partial_k\\=B(A)_k\\\not = &0
\end{align}

Am I missing something or is the paper wrong?

Comment: This question might fit better on Math Overflow.

Comment: Now there is also MO-version of the question: [A question about a theorem in 'Quantum dynamical semigroups generated by noncommutative unbounded elliptic operators'](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309522).

Comment: Maybe you should also cite some definitions from the article. For instance: what is  $\mathcal{D}$. Is $AB$ a product or a composition, in case $A$ or $B$ are functions.

Comment: @denklo thx for the advice, I just added it to the description of the question

Answer (score 1):

Using the relation $\partial_k a = a \partial_k + (a)_k$

$$[A, B\partial_k + \partial_k B] = A B\partial_k + A \partial_k B - B \partial_k A -\partial_k BA = AB \partial_k + AB \partial_k + A(B)_k - AB \partial_k -B(A)_k - (AB)_k - AB \partial_k $$
cancelling anything out and using product rule $(ab)_k = (a)_kb + (b)_ka$
$$[A, B\partial_k + \partial_k B] = A(B)_k - B(A)_k - (A)_kB- (B)_kA = -2 (A)_k B$$

Comment: Where does that product rule come from? I think in the expansion of $(a)_kb+(b)_ka$ there is even not a term of $ab\partial_k$.

Comment: Should the forth term in the last part of the first equation be $-BA\partial_k$ since $B\partial_kA=BA\partial_k+B(A)_k$?

Comment: @aeei.w.1995 $A$ and $B$ are just functions and thus commute. At least i remember to have read in the paper you cite that $W$ is just some function $\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @josephz no. This is why the notation $(a)_k$ was introduced, i believe: to differentiate between a series of operators and functions and the simple partial derivative of a function.

Comment: @denklo But here is the composition of A and B as $AB(u)=A(B(u))$ which does not commute

Comment: @aeei.w.1995 Ok, maybe i'm missing something, but in the article, e.g. on page 7, they state: $$ \mathcal{D} = C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$$. Also, if $AB$ really is a composition and not simply a product of two functions, an expression of type $W^2 W_k \partial_k$, as you present in your question, makes no sense, since $W^2: \mathbb{R}^d -> \mathbb{R} $ and same for $W_k \partial_k$. Finally, $AB$ being the composition, what is the meaning of the rightmost term of your cited deduction? $A [B+C] = A \circ (B + C)$ or $A [B+C] = A \circ B + A \circ C$?

Comment: @denklo I think you are right, this should be the function product. Thanks a lot for the help!